# Attempting to input data to input tag but Sendkeys not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium-webdriver

I'm attempting to automate application process for a website I work on. I'm using selenium web-driver and node.js. I'm able to navigate through the different pages but I'm unable to get any text in the input fields. Can someone assist me with this? Please see my code below.

```
"use strict";

var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var browser = new webdriver.Builder().usingServer().withCapabilities({'browserName': 'chrome' }).build();

function clickLink(link) {
    link.click();
}

function handleFailure(err) {
    console.error('Something went wrong\n', err.stack, '\n');
    closeBrowser();
}

function createOptumID() {
    return browser.findElements(webdriver.By.id('createOptumID')).then(function(result) {
        return result[0];
    });
}

function newOptumID() {
    return browser.findElements(webdriver.By.id('firstNameId_input')).then(function(result) {
        return result[0];
    });
}

function closeBrowser() {
    browser.quit();
}

browser.get('https://qa-ind.mahealthconnector.optum.com/individual/');
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('enrollment')).click();
browser.wait(createOptumID, 100000).then(clickLink);
browser.wait(newOptumID, 100000).then(clickLink);
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('firstNameId_input')).sendKeys('Erin');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `executeScript` method of webdriver object like the following:

```
//runs the script get the element by id then set it's value attribute to 'Erin'
webdriver.executeScript("document.getElementById('firstNameId_input').setAttribute('value', 'Erin')");
```

Comment: @PaulPinho You're welcome. I find when using Selenium that the `executeScript` is an excellent tool for utilizing javascript to do alot of the necessary automation actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can get value of input field by using getAttribute method of webelement
browser.findElement(webdriver.By.id('firstNameId_input')).getAttribute("value");